# SSL/TLS: Version Change during Renegotiation or Resumption?

Tags: tls

Can the version proposed by Client be changed during SSL Resumption or Renegotiation?

**Resumption Case:**
In case of Resumption, as I understand, Client will send a Client Hello with the Session ID of an already established session. The Cipher should be kept same, but can we change the version in the Client Hello? I am unable to find which section in RFC 5246 or the preceding RFCs speaks about this.

**Renegotiation Case:**
SSL/TLS supports renegotiation feature to allow the Client and Server to change the Cipher negotiated during the first handshake which provided the flexibility to change the Authentication Method as well as Cipher for Data Transfer. But, can the Version also be changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [current TLS standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) is not very clear on how versions should be handled. Annex E.1 contains some information, from which we can see that the *implicit idea* is that the selected version depends on what the client and server *support*, not on what the client and server may elect to use on a whim. If a client supports up to TLS 1.2 and a server up to TLS 1.1, then they *should* use TLS 1.1, always. As such, there should be no question of "changing the version" when resuming a session, or renegotiating.

There are several version fields:

- Each "record" has a version field.
- The ClientHello message contains the highest version supported by the client.
- The ServerHello message contains the version that *will* be used on this connection.

Supposedly, the client will send its first ClientHello as a record bearing a version number 3.x for some value of "x"; 3.0 will maximize interoperability. Once the server has responded with a ServerHello stating that version 3.y will be used, then both client and server must use 3.y records. This makes version jumps somewhat delicate during a renegotiation. Also, CBC-encrypted TLS 1.1+ records are not compatible with SSL 3.0 / TLS 1.0 records (because of the additional per-record IV), so record-level versions are important once the first ChangeCipherSpec has been sent/received.

For a session resumption, annex E.1 states that:

> Whenever a client already knows the highest protocol version known to
> a server (for example, when resuming a session), it SHOULD initiate
> the connection in that native protocol.

from which I infer that if the previous session used version 3.y, then the client should use *records* with version 3.y. However, nothing prevents it from advertising an higher version number in the ClientHello.

Also, derivation of the master key into encryption and MAC keys uses the TLS PRF, which depends on the protocol version (TLS 1.0 and 1.1 use the same PRF, but not SSL 3.0, and neither TLS 1.2). Resuming a session with a different version is looking for trouble.

The whole area is murky. See for instance [this Mozilla/Firefox bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=774547). In my experience, the following rules should be followed to minimize issues:

**Rules for the client:**

- Send the first record as version 3.0.
- Always advertise in the ClientHello the maximum supported version (e.g. 3.3 for TLS 1.2).
- When the server responds with a ServerHello, use the version sent by the server as new version for all subsequent records, cryptographic computations, and protocol details.
- Once the server has sent a ServerHello, enforce incoming record versions: subsequent records from the server should use *that* version. If a record from the server advertises another version, abort.
- When renegotiating, if the server tries to use another version than previously, abort.

**Rules for the server:**

- Ignore the version on incoming records, during the initial steps of the connection.
- Once you have sent your ServerHello, enforce record versions: all subsequent records from the client should use that version.
- When resuming a session, reuse the same version, as long as the version in the ClientHello allows it; otherwise, do a full handshake (e.g. if the previous session was TLS 1.1 and the new ClientHello says 1.2, resume with version 1.1; if the previous session was TLS 1.1 and the new ClientHello says 1.0, do not resume, do a new full 1.0 handshake).
- When renegotiating, verify that the version advertised in the new ClientHello is compatible with the current version -- but do not change the current version. If the first handshake was 1.1, the second handshake will be 1.1, even if the new ClientHello says 1.2.

It is pretty much guaranteed that there are some widely deployed implementations which get it wrong at some point.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like, technically, yes - since version is part of the client hello, which is repeated in both a resumption and renegotiation.

But you're right that there's no explicit section in the RFP on it.

I did find, this, however:

> ```
>   Extensions should, as far as possible, be designed to prevent any
>   attack that forces use (or non-use) of a particular feature by
>   manipulation of handshake messages.  This principle should be
>   followed regardless of whether the feature is believed to cause a
>   security problem.
>
>   Often the fact that the extension fields are included in the
>   inputs to the Finished message hashes will be sufficient, but
>   extreme care is needed when the extension changes the meaning of
>   messages sent in the handshake phase.  Designers and implementors
>   should be aware of the fact that until the handshake has been
>   authenticated, active attackers can modify messages and insert,
>   remove, or replace extensions.
> ```

And there is a section in the end on [version rollback attacks](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#appendix-F.1.2).  These sound quite different from either case mentioned in the question, but it would seem to me that if you used the version setting of the client hello in the cases you mention, you'd be at risk to a version rollback attack, and I wonder if this would imply that you shouldn't really use it that way.